# SOLR: Search for a value in multiple fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I am looking for a way of querying for values in multiple fields. Basically i am building a simple search engine where user can type ie. "Java How to XML JSON" and it will search for these values in 3 different fields `categories, tags, description`.

I read on some blog I should query all fields `q=*:*` and then filter based on those fields for example `fq=categories:java,xml,how,to,json  description:java,xml,how,to,json  tags:java,xml,how,to,json`

This works :| But it seems incorrect to just copy paste values like this.

Is there a correct way of doing this? I have been researching this for some time but i havent found a solution.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defType=edismax` to get the extended dismax handler. This is meant to handle user typed queries (i.e. what you'd type in). You can then use `qf` (query fields) to tell the edismax handler which fields you want to search (and an optional weight for each field):

```
q=Java How to XML JSON&defType=edismax&qf=categories^5 tags description
```

.. will search each part of the string "Java How to XML JSON" in all the fields, and any hits in the `categories` field will be weighted five times higher than hits in the other two fields.