# Search multiple Solr fields for value

Tags: solr

I would like to search for a string in Solr, but I want the search to consider only a few fields.

For example: search for the string 'Solr' in fields 'title', 'description' and 'tags' and ignore anything in other fields.

I am aware of this: `q=(title:"Solr" OR description:"Solr" OR tags: "Solr")` but this is a bit verbose. Would be better if there's a way to specify the search query and the fields to search.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231742/solr-search-for-a-value-in-multiple-fields) about the same thing but the solution involves using `edismax` query parser, I would like to stick to the standard parser.

Comment: Add a separate field that have all the fields you want to search and use a copy field instruction to populate it with the values from the other fields. Unless you want to score hits in the different fields differently that should work fine.

Comment: @MatsLindh this should definitely work! But I am asking if another way using query params, that I'm not aware of, exists.

Comment: In previous versions of Solr you could achieve what you are trying to do via LocalParams and Dereferencing (https://library.brown.edu/create/digitaltechnologies/solr-localparams-and-dereferencing/) but Solr has restricted their use significantly in newer versions since they could be used for security exploits.

Comment: @HectorCorrea That feature is the same as using the edismax handler as noted in the question by OP that he/she is trying to avoid using. It only changes the `qf` parameter as used by edismax, it does not work with the regular query parser (which uses `df` - the default field - which only supports a single field as far as I know)